# Arduino Nano joystick x2 / potentiometer

Tags: arduino-nano, potentiometer, joystick

will i be able to connect up all these parts to an arduino Nano 
i noticed i will need to connect to the nanos v5 to the 2 joysticks and potentiometer slider if i share the voltage will it still function as intended 
[image]
**Parts**

x1 = USB Arduino Nano V3.0 ATMEGA328P CH340G 5V 16M Micro-Controller Arduino

x2 = 3D Analog Joystick for Sony PSP 1000 Consol 
+5v (possible 10kOhm resistance)

x1 = Electronic slider 10K potentiometer Slider Module for Arduino
Voltage: 3.3V or 5V / Resistance: 10K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work. The potentiometer slider will source about 5mA and each joystick axis about 50mA. In total this gives you 205mA. Here it is important, that your power source can provide enough current. If you are using an USB port from your computer, this would result in 500mA maximum that can be drawn from the bus. Since this is shared with the Arduino you can externally use about 400mA

For more information about current ratings refer to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/how-much-current-can-i-draw-from-the-arduinos-pins)

EDIT: Since your previous resistance values were not correct, I edit my answer.

When all potentiometers have 10kOhm resistance (and this seems to be more likely the right values), each one draws about 5mA from the 5V pin (You can calculate this with Ohm's Law `U = R * I`, which gives you `I = U / R`. So you have to divide the voltage by the resistance.). So you aren't getting anywhere near the problematic currents. These potentiometers are designed this way. They don't want to draw a high amount of power, but only setting a certain voltage to the output pin.

Comment: I suspect the 100R pots are somewhat erroneously labelled. Especially as the slider certainly is incorrectly labelled.

Comment: ohh i could not find the joystick specs on that front this is my first project 
this was listed as the slider i thought the 10k ment 10,000 did i get that wrong
Voltage: 3.3V or 5V
Port: Analog
Resistance: 10K

Comment: 10k does mean 10,000 - but your schematic shows 1k for the slider and a mere 100R for the pots, which are almost certainly more likely to be around 10k or higher.

Comment: updated the image and info related to the parts still trying to find more info regarding the Analog Joystick Sony PSP 1000

Comment: The only way to be sure is to measure they resistance. But I also found a joystick, that is labeled as PSP on ebay. They claim to have 10kOhm resistance: [Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/New-PSP-2-Axis-Analog-Thumb-GAME-Joystick-Module-3V-5V-For-arduino-PSP/401104248437?hash=item5d63ad1e75:g:HcEAAOSwjqVZNSzw)

Comment: thanks for that been looking everywhere for some more info related to joystick